# VB 6 InteropForms: The file [...] was not registerable as an ActiveX Component

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I am working my way through the walk-through and I got as far as trying to load the control into the VB 6 toolbox.

I can load the DLL as a reference, but not as an ActiveX Component. When I try I get the message "InteropForms: The file [...] was not registerable as an ActiveX Component.".

I can create the control at runtime as a normal COM object.

Jonathan

EDIT:

If I try RegSvr32 I get this message:

> [...] was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.
>   This file can not be registered.

EDIT 2:

If i register it with RegAsm, it appears in the component's list. However I get a error loading the DLL if I check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but everything works if I run VB 6 and VS 2010 on the same machine. There must be something in the compile or post-compile step that I'm missing.

EDIT:

Ok, so what you need to do is run `regAsm` with the `/codebase` and `/tlb` options.

EDIT 2:

If you make any changes to the .NET dll, make sure you reregister it.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/Interop-Forms-Toolkit-2-0-Tutorial**

1. register your library first

like this
If you want to add dll file in you vb6 project

**Don't do**

```vb
regasm labelwinform.dll /tlb:labelwinform.dll /codebase
```

It will not register the dll.I face this problem
so

**Solution**

```vb
regasm labelwinform.dll /tlb:labelwinform.tlb /codebase
```

[image]

**add reference in vb6  Project menu->references**
[image]

**add component in vb6  Project menu->component**

[image]
**final like control like this**
[image]

Axtivex component not registerable error due to dll file not registered properly in production(installing application on another computer or customer computer).So my i approach is advanced installer .it is my personal opinion.

[image]